# IKEv1 Phase 1, authentication with signature, sending certificates "optionally"

Tags: signature, authentication, certificates, ipsec

At RFC2409, section 5.1, authentication header is like:

HDR*, IDii, [ CERT, ] SIG_I

HDR is an ISAKMP header whose exchange type is the mode.  When
writen as HDR* it indicates payload encryption.

IDii is ID of initiator

[CERT] means that sending certificate is optional

SIG_I is signature of initiator.

Why sending certificate payload is optional? How just sending signature is enough for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Authenticated Key Exchange frameworks (AKE) allow the communication partner's certificate / long-term public key to be known in advance. This is used, for example, in Lightweight AKEs to keep the bandwidth requirement as low as possible. For another example where certificates are not sent: https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/lake/about/.

Comment: Looking back at the concerns they had in 1998, they weren't concerned that much with bandwidth - the complexity of PKI (which was even worse then than it is now; they didn't have today's tooling) was what concerned them...

Answer (score 1):

> Why sending certificate payload is optional? How just sending signature is enough for authentication?

I believe that the intent was to support cases where you don't have a PKI, and hence don't have certificates.  In those situations, you would configure the public key of the peer on each device; in that specific case, the signature was sufficient (because the authentic public key was already known).